# When click action bar icon i want display customized dialog box.(i.e)xml our dialog

Tags: android-studio

My click action bar icon I want display dialog box.
(i.e)i am using custom dialog .
for dialog box i create xml layout.
The program i tried given below...

Actually i want that when click icon in action it display the custom dialog box (custom ).

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.icon:
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dailog);
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog Example");

        Button dialogButtonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        Button dialogButtonOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        // Click cancel to dismiss android custom dialog box
        dialogButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

When run app there no output

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `dialog.show()` to display the dialog;

Also you can't use a `return` in a `switch` you need to use `break`.

Edit:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.icon:
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dailog);
    dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog Example");

    Button dialogButtonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    Button dialogButtonOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    // Click cancel to dismiss android custom dialog box
    dialogButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    break;
}
```

Edit 2: Alternatively you could use the library [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs), it's really easy to use.

Comment: hi, henrique:i tried});
                dialog.show();
                break;
        }

return true;
    }

Comment: but there no progress

Comment: The return is outside the switch isn't?
So it shouldn't matter, i misread it being inside the first time.

Comment: I added more info.